# SQL to LINQ translation

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT RID FROM Recipe_Ingredient WHERE IID IN 
           (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Ingredients WHERE Name IN('broccoli','egg')))
```

I am trying to translate this sql query into linq. So far I got no luck.

I receive a string array of ingredients. So far I got to this:

```
List<string> searchList = new List<string>(search);
var ing = context.Ingredients.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchList.ToString())).ToList();
var recing = context.Recipe_Ingredients.Where(x => ing.Contains(x.IID)).Select(x => x.IID).ToList();
var rec = context.Recipes.Where(x => recing.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

But by using the debugger it fails on the `ing` because the `searchList` is not contained in `x.Name` (`searchList[0] = 'egg'` when I use it for testing)

[image: db schema]

Comment: Do you have navigation properties in your generated class (for example an IngredientList property in Recipe_Ingredient) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small mistake in ing line. And first 2 ToList methods are redundant.

```
List<string> searchList = new List<string>(search);
var ing = context.Ingredients.Where(x => searchList.Contains(x.Name));
var recing = context.Recipe_Ingredients.Where(x => ing.Contains(x.IID)).Select(x => x.IID);
var rec = context.Recipes.Where(x => recing.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not translating the `MIN(...)` in the SQL.

```
var searchList = new List<string>(search); // broccoli, egg
var recipies = context.Recipes
    .Where(r =>
        context.Recipe_Ingredients
            .Where(ri =>
                context.Ingredients
                    .Where(i => searchList.Contains(i.Name))
                    .Select(i => i.ID)
                    .Min() == ri.IID
            )
            .Select(ri => ri.RID)
        .Contains(r.ID)
    )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're inverting the Contains (you're not doing an in clause)
2. Min(Id) can't be a list (in your sql query), it will be a unique id.
3. Don't put `ToList()` too early, it will generate multiple queries.

So to stay near your code, you could do

```
List<string> searchList = new List<string>(search);
var ingId = context.Ingredients.Where(x => searchList.Contains(x.Name)).Min(m => m.Id);
var recing = context.Recipe_Ingredients.Where(x => x.IID == ingId).Select(x => x.RID);
var rec = context.Recipes.Where(x => recing.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: You usage of `Min(m => m.Id)` **will** generate a query.

Comment: @Maarten I know, I know. A choice between readability and perf... (or in this case, to stay as closed as possible from OP's attempt)